# Python Code to read File and Extract data

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop, io

I am working on a small code assignment and stumbled upon something that I don't understand. So I am hoping someone can help me and give me an explanation.

So I am working on a code to write a program that prompts for a file name. The file can be found here: http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt. Using that file, I read through it and look for lines of the form:

```
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475.
```

My job is to count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values.

I have the following code so far:

```
#fname = File Path
fh = open(fname)
emptyl=[]
for line in fh:

    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): continue
    line=line.strip()
    print line

    for confidence in line:
        try:
            x = float(line[-6:])
            print x
            y = emptyl.append(x)
            print y
        except:
            pass
```

When I print Line, I get 27 lines with `X-DSPAM-Confidence:"`. However when I print `x` to see the result of my code, I get each number that shows up in print line repeated 26 times. Why are the numbers repeating? Also when I print `y`, I get `None`. I also don't understand why its giving me `None` instead of an actual number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of this extra loop `for confidence in line:`:

```
emptyl=[]
with open(fname) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): 
            continue
        line = line.strip()
        try:
            x = float(line[-6:])
            emptyl.append(x)
        except Value Error:
            pass
```

You have two nested loops. First you loop through all lines:

```
for line in fh:
```

and for each line you loop through all characters in this line:

```
  for confidence in line:
```

and append this number: `float(line[-6:])` again and again.

`append()`  is a method that modifies the object it belongs to. So:

```
emptyl.append(x)
```

modifies `emptyl`. The return value of this action is `None`. Typically, it is not used because the action we are up to is modifying `emptyl`.

Comment: why not use the with statement. It will clean up the file resource as well.